# carousel is not show first picture

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I have written the following code for carousel, but it's not showing my first picture. Is my code right or am I missing something?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
       <% @post.each_with_index do |photo,n| %>
       <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to="#{n}" class="#{'active' if n==0}"></li>
       <% end %>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <% if Post.first==nil %>
                <img src="http://hometelvietnam.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/a614f72d-c487-438a-a16f-514e65406ed2.jpg" >
                <div class="slider">
                <button class="btn btn-danger"><h1 style="margin:5px; shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5 black;">Become a host now</h1></button>
                </div>
            <%else%>
            <% image_tag Post.first.post_picture %>
            <%end%>
        </div>
        <% @post.drop(1).each do |photo| %>
        <div class="item">
            <%= link_to (image_tag photo.post_picture),photo %>
        </div>
        <%end%>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `=` in the `image_tag(...)` method:

```
<%= image_tag Post.first.post_picture %>
```

Comment: <% image_tag Post.first.post_picture %> this command is picture 1, If u do not want to repeat 2 times, u need drop(1)